# Select single features in selection

Tags: qgis, select

I have a selection of 30 features from a dataset in QGIS. I want to inspect every single feature one after another with the attributetable and the icon 'zoom to selected object'.
If I click on one row the selection is gone and only the clicked row is selected.
Is there any button which I have to press? 
I don´t want to store the selection as a extra file.

Comment: If you don't click onto the rownumber, only into the cells, the selection should be kept.

Comment: If you right-click on a value inside the attribute table, there are options such as `Zoom to Feature`, `Pan to Feature` and even a `Flash Feature` which flashes the feature to distinguish it from others.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just founded out ^^

Comment: This new plugins may also help https://www.xl-optim.com/get-them-filtered/

Answer (score 6):

If you *right-click* on a value inside the attribute table, there are options such as the following to examine each selected feature individually:

- Zoom to Feature
- Pan to Feature
- Flash Feature (which flashes the feature to distinguish it from others)

[image: Examine selected feature]

---

*Tested on QGIS 3.8.1 for Win 7 64-bit.*